# Render data from an API into a Vue Template

Tags: vue.js

I am successfully fetching api in vue but how to properly render it? "undefined id of null" is what I get in console error

this is the axios call I made

```
  axios.getOrder(id).then(response => {
    this.cart_content = response.data
    console.log(this.cart_content)
  })
```

this is how I'm trying to render in in vue

```
       <div v-if="cart_content">
          <ul v-for="i in cart_content" :key="i.id">
            <li>
              <p>{{i.name}}</p>
              <p>{{i.items.quantity}}</p>
              <p>{{i.items.unit_price}}</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

the API is available when I console.log, it looks something like this.

```
id:'',
data:array[1]
```

the "data array" is where the details I need, can anyone tell me how to get these data.

Answer (score 2):

Because your data is collected in an asynchronous way, it's not initially available to your component, hence it errors out. You'll need to fetch the data on a component lifecycle method, something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cart_content: [],
      id: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getOrder(this.id)
  },
  methods: {
    getOrder(id) {
      axios.getOrder(id)
        .then(response => {
          this.cart_content = response.data;
        });
    }
  }
}
```

<kbd>[**Working CodeSandbox Example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-archimedes-8slhe?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)</kbd>

Comment: Hi, I appreciate how you try to explain your solution to me, though I can't somehow make it work since your solution is static the ID that I used to filter whats in API is from a table I forgot to include the table but it's just a simple table with the ID which is passed to the function when clicked can you enlighten me to that part please

Comment: also this created method fires right after I refresh and still not getting the data from API

Comment: @ErrolBoneo If you could add more details about your code I can try to help you further

Answer (score 0):

```js
methods: {
getsomething(){
var apicall = axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
apicall.then(resp => {
for(var x = 0; x < resp.data.length; x++){
for(var dataCount = 0; dataCount < resp.data.length; dataCount++)
{
if(resp.data[dataCount].id == resp.data[x].id)
{
this.cart_content = resp.data[x].id;
}
}
}
})
}
}
```

```html
<template>
<div>
  <div v-if="cart_content">
          <ul v-for="i in cart_content" :key="i.id">
            <li>
              <p>{{i.name}}</p>
              <p>{{i.items.quantity}}</p>
              <p>{{i.items.unit_price}}</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
</div>
</template>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my code is not wrong after all I just had to include the name of the array of object from the response to get what I wanted (cart_content.data) in v-for thanks for helping me out here guys I appreciate your time